# Fullscreen UIView will not animate its appearance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I need some help with some basic transition work. I think I don't understand this conceptually.

I load a main view which loads a 'log in screen' in its viewDidLoad.
The 'log in screen' is a custom xib + custom view controller. 
It is loaded in the following way:

```
ISSplashScreenViewController* splashScreenController = [[ISSplashScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ISSplashScreen" bundle:nil];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:splashScreenController.view cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.5];

[splashScreenController viewWillAppear:YES];
[self.view addSubview:splashScreenController.view];
[splashScreenController viewDidAppear:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

All I can see is the status bar animating (and I think this is because it is hidden in the main window but I call for it in the log in screen's viewDidLoad).

The body of the log in screen 'just appears'.

I was wondering if someone could explain why this isn't working and perhaps suggest what i could do to make it work. I think I have to remove the main view from the application's sub views and then load the log in view.

I tried this also, but it doesnt work. The main view just sits there.

```
[splashScreenController viewWillAppear:YES];
[self.view.superview addSubview:splashScreenController.view];
[self.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:splashScreenController.view];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[splashScreenController viewDidAppear:YES];
```

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `-setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:` with `self.view` rather than the splash-screen controller’s view.

Comment: I tried that and nothing has changed. I tried setting the animation for both controllers and the status bar's appearing now occurs twice as fast. The view im trying to load still doesn't animate, though.